# Nous fait (un) signe de la main

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Mais soudain, M qui marche en tête du groupe nous fait **un** signe de la
> main.

Il est possible d'omettre l'article indéfini devant "signe". Quelle phrase serait plus belle, avec ou sans l'article ?

Comment: — Mais soudain, le *signe manuel* de M. qui marche en tête du groupe, nous  (fait …, donne une indication/un ordre).  

— Mais soudain, le geste de M. qui marche en tête du groupe *est signe de* (d'attention, de fatigue/repos … ou tout autre information).   

— Mais soudain, [le geste/mouvement de] la main de M., qui marche en tête du groupe, *signe* la fin du périple, l'arrivée/le changement …

Comment: À mon avis ici ça n'a aucune importance, il n'y a aucune raison grammaticale pour l'un ou pour l'autre choix. Mais je rejoins @Personne pour dire qu'on attend la raison de ce signe. Si, au lieu de poursuivre le récit  en donnant la raison dans la phrase suivante, tu choisissais de poursuive la même phrase, peut-être que pour une raison de rythme tu pourras te poser la question.

Comment: @Personne et None, merci :) // Il y a une explication dans la phrase suivante.

Answer (score 1):

Que l'on utilise l'article ou non, le sens dépend de la définition suivante du TLFi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/signe)) 1. Geste, mimique ou mouvement volontaire destiné à communiquer quelque chose à quelqu'un, à manifester ou faire savoir quelque chose.

Lorsqu'on utilise l'article, le sens est très général ou il peut correspondre à l'usage sans l'article ; dans ce sens général, il n'existe pas un contexte fort d'implication entre la personne faisant le signe, et celles à qui il est destiné. Le geste peut être plus ou moins gratuit. Dans ces cas-là, il est correct d'utiliser l'article ; ne pas l'utiliser implique le contexte d'une relation qui n'existe pas, et donc la communication est faussée.

Les cas de non utilisation de l'article sont apparentés aux cas d'utilisation des expressions suivantes (qui dépendent de la définition ci-dessus). Dans ces cas-là le signe est plus ou moins conventionnel, il a un sens qui est reconnu ou reconnaissable par les deux partis.

> **Faire signe (à qqn) que**.
> ♦ Faire signe que non.
> ♦ Voilà ce qu'on ne peut obtenir au cabaret, je dis dans les meilleurs: une daube de bœuf où la gelée ne sente pas la colle, et où le bœuf ait pris parfum des carottes, c'est admirable! Permettez-moi d'y revenir, ajouta-t-il en faisant signe qu'il voulait encore de la gelée (Proust,J. filles en fleurs,1918, p. 458).
> ♦ Nica me fait signe qu'elle va monter. Je lui réponds de la main que c'est pas la peine (Vercel,Cap. Conan,1934, p. 99).
> **Faire signe à qqn de + inf**.
> ♦ Moi aussi je te voudrais près de moi, et je ne te dis pas que quelque jour je ne te ferai pas signe de venir (A. Daudet, Pt Chose,1868, p. 121).
> ♦ [Elle] aperçoit dans la cour un cocher (...). Elle lui fait signe de monter (Goncourt,Journal,1887, p. 634).
> **Faire signe à qqn**.
> ♦ Je suis naïf au point d'être Par moments persuadé Que Vénus, à sa fenêtre, M'a fait signe à Saint-Mandé (Hugo,Toute la lyre, t. 2, 1885, p. 101).

En examinant les exemples, on voit que dans tous les cas sauf le dernier il existe une relation évidente qui justifie le signe.

1. Dans le cas l'homme attablé le signe est compris d'une personne dont la responsabilité est de servir les clients (probablement).
2. Nica sait que la personne à qui elle fait un signe comprend quelque chose de précis codé dans le signe.
3. L'emploi est figuratif dans cet exemple ;
4. Ne compte pas, sens figuré
5. Signe conventionnel

La définition du Wiktionnaire rend cela explicite.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_signe)) Locution verbale
>
> **faire signe** \fɛʁ siɲ\ transitif indirect
> Indiquer sa volonté par un signe.

Elle n'est cependant pas tout à fait précise. Il peut assez souvent ne pas être question d'indiquer une volonté ; au lieu de cela, est indiqué un renseignement.

- Nous cherchions la balle qui venait de tomber dans le taillis lorsque qu'un promeneur qui l'avait vue atterrir nous fit signe  de chercher vers la droite.
- Nous cherchions la balle qui venait de tomber dans le taillis lorsque qu'un promeneur qui l'avait vue atterrir nous fit signe de la main, il fallait  chercher vers la droite.

Considérant maintenant le contexte de la phrase dans la demande, tout dépend du signe.  Si le signe correspond à une attente du groupe, on peut utiliser l'article mais le plus souvent il ne sera pas utilisé.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fait%20signe%20de%20la%20main%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

- Mais soudain, M qui marche en tête du groupe nous fait signe de la main,
  c'est la pause
  la piste a été atteinte, sur la droite
  il ne faut plus faire de bruit
  il faut ralentir

Si le signe ne correspond pas à une attente du groupe, de préférence   l'article est utilisé.

- Mais soudain, M qui marche en tête du groupe nous fait un signe de la main,
  il a l'air d'être en détresse
  on ne sait pas ce qui se passe, on dirait qu'il cherche à nous avertir
  il fait tournoyer  son doigt au-dessus de sa tête, peut-être a-t-il aperçu des vautours

Il n'est pas question d'esthétique du langage.

Answer (score 1):

1. Il est possible d'omettre l'article indéfini devant "signe"?

Oui.

2. Quelle phrase serait plus belle, avec ou sans l'article ?

C'est subjectif, mais je préfère avec. Sans l'article, on a l'impression qu'il manque quelque chose, *nous fait signe de nous arrêter*, *nous fait signe de le suivre*, etc. alors qu'avec l'article, il ne manque pas d'information immédiate, on sait qu'un signe a été fait. Je trouve aussi que *nous fait un signe de la main* est plus harmonieux, peut-être parce que c'est un octosyllabe, mais c'est encore plus subjectif.

Comment: Je trouve plus harmonieux d'omettre l'article, mais c'est probablement parce que le russe ne possède pas d'articles. // _Si le signe correspond à une attente du groupe, on peut utiliser l'article mais le plus souvent il ne sera pas utilisé._ (LPH) Intuitivement, je pense que c'est vrai, mais encore une fois il se peut que j'aie cette impression sous l'influence du russe.