# Ce n'est pas (un) bon signe

Tags: expressions, articles

> Ce n'est pas bon signe.
>
> Ce n'est pas **un** bon signe.

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre les deux variantes ? Par exemple, est-il possible de mettre l'article indéfini devant *bon signe* dans cette phrase de Marcel Aymé :

> Etre heureux, **ce n'est pas bon signe**, c'est que le malheur a
> manqué le coche, il arrivera par le suivant. ([source](https://www.dicocitations.com/citations/citation-1377.php))

Answer (score 1):

L'article indéfini est toujours possible mais il n'apporte rien.

Il me semble qu'*être bon signe* est un peu plus abstrait, mais je ne trouve pas d'exemple où ce serait flagrant. Peut être que des événements répétitifs s'accordent moins bien avec l'unicité qu'implique l'article :

> *S'il t'appelle tous les jours, **c'est bon signe** !*

Je suis tombé sur [ce manuscrit](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b52509623w/f85.item.zoom) (*Livre de la chace, lequel fist le conte DE FOIZ*) - Gaston Phoebus, Comte de Foix, XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle qui montre que l'expression est ancienne.

> *Et ce est cerf qui c'est outre marche c'est quil mette le pié derrière sur celuy devant sans outre marcher **encore n’est ce pas bon signe** ; mes s’il met le pié de derrière loing de celuy devant, **c’est bon signe**, ou s'il marche derrière plus large que devant **encore est ce bon signe***

Comment: Oui, quelqu'un m'avait dit que l'omission de l'article rend l'expression plus abstraite. Mais ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/nous-fait-un-signe-de-la-main?rq=1), je pensais que la logique devrait être semblable, qu'avec l'article, le tour serait plus beau, mais non, ce n'est pas le cas. Peut-être parce que là, il y a un verbe d'action + article, alors qu'ici le verbe _être_.

Comment: C'est que *être bon signe* est proche d'une locution. On retrouve ça avec *je te souhaite bon vent* qui est beaucoup plus générique et courant que *je te souhaite un bon vent*, pareil avec *je te souhaite bon courage* alors qu'au contraire, ce sera plutôt *je te souhaite un bon anniversaire* parce qu'il est unique et bien défini.

Comment: pour l'article indéfini, il me semble indiqué pour un évènement unique : **un** chat noir a traversé la route: ce n'est pas **un** bon signe.

Comment: @Archemar C'est vrai mais l'absence d'article est tout aussi possible dans cet exemple.